# How to change the background color on a Java panel?

Tags: java, background-color

Right now, the background I get is a grey. I want to change it to black. I tried doing something like setBackground(color.BLACK); but it didnt work. Any suggestions?

```
public test() 
{
    setTitle("Adjustment Form");
    setSize(670,450);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,6,2,2));
    setVisible(true);   
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could call:

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
```

Or add a JPanel to the JFrame your using. Then add your components to the JPanel. This will allow you to call

```
setBackground(Color.black);
```

on the JPanel to set the background color.

Comment: I went ahead and did the getContentPane method and it worked.

Comment: Hi, I want the colour #3ce3b4, how can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

I think what he is trying to say is to use the 
`getContentPane().setBackground(Color.the_Color_you_want_here)`

but if u want to set the color to any other then the JFrame, you use the `object.setBackground(Color.the_Color_you_want_here)`

Eg:

```
jPanel.setbackground(Color.BLUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`setBackground()` is the right method to use. Did you repaint after you changed it? If you change it before you make the panel (or its containing frame) visible it should work

Comment: there is no frame. i just made a gridbox. and I just add components like buttons and stuff to it.

Comment: @Faraz How are you displaying it then? You probably want to add the panel to a `JFrame`, that's normally how they're used

Comment: I can display it without the frame or a panel. I actually made a keypad to do simple subtraction without using any of frame or panel stuff. I just used the gridlayout

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that we are dealing with a JFrame?  The visible portion in the content pane - you have to use jframe.getContentPane().setBackground(...);