# How do I change the background color of a JPanel with a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I need to have three buttons in my program (the last one is an exit button and it already works) the other two need to change the color of the `JPanel` background between blue and red.

I need to know what goes in the `AtionListeners` so that when the buttons are pressed it changes the background color.

This is the class so far :

```
package myPackageNameGoesHere;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class EventPanel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 123796234;

private JButton blueButton;
private JButton redButton;
private JButton exitButton;

public EventPanel() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));

    this.blueButton = new JButton("Blue");
    this.add(this.blueButton);

    this.redButton = new JButton("Red");
    this.add(this.redButton);

    this.exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    this.exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitListener());
    this.add(this.exitButton);
}

private class BlueListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent blue) {
        // What goes here?????

    }
}

private class RedListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent red) {
        // What goes here????

    }
}
private class ExitListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent exit) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219919/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-java-panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to declare a listener class for each button, you can just use the same one and add if statement to determine from which button the action come from.

```
if (e.getSource() == blueButton) {// e is the ActionEvent
    blueButton.getParent().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
} else if(e.getSource() == redButton) {
    redButton.getParent().setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set the background color of the button's parent component

```
Component component = (Component) event.getSource();
component.getParent().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```